# CodeIgniter Url Rewrite (language dependent)

Tags: codeigniter, localization, url-rewriting

So, i have my .htaccess, my controllers, everything is going fine. I added localization, so now i have Portuguese(Default), English and Italian.
 I am using the _lang files in the appplication/languages directory, i am using session->userdata('lang') and everything works fine.
My controllers are named with portuguese words, after the top menu. What i'm looking for is:
to rewrite my url, changing the name of the controller, depending on the session->userdata('lang').
Is this even possible? how?

Thank you

So i am trying, as InFog suggested, in the routes file:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('lang') == 'english') { 
    $route['novidades/([a-z]+)'] = 'news/$1'; 
}
```

but i just get a blank screen when i open the application.
And i've tried it without the if clause, and nothing happens, when i go to

> http://localhost/myapp/novidades

the url stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using CodeIgniter Routes. You can do it editing the file 'system/application/config/routes.php:

```
$route['news/([a-z]+)'] = 'noticias/$1';
```

This way an URL like '/news/run-fools' will be remaped to 'noticias/run-fools'. Now you can have just one controller =)

Good Luck

Comment: I edited my question after your comment. Can you please check it out?

Comment: i was going at it the wrong way, i wanted codeigniter to replace the main uri with the localized one, and what i had to do was write the hrefs language dependant Solved, thanks everyone

Comment: Hi! You don't need that 'if', just add the route, this way you'll have two addresses to the same page. Try using (:any) instead ([a-z]+).

Answer (score 1):

Override CI_Router to translate the name in the fetch_class() method to change controllers. Override fetch_method() to change methods.

Comment: i have to go and investigate how that overriding can be made. i'll leave some feedback later. Thanx